# Having trouble updating database table with strings sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite

Am having an issue with python, sqlite3 where I can update a table with numbers (int or decimal) but not strings.
[link to a screenshot of program running here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGRju.png)

```
def amendRec():    #FIX ME PLEASE
edit="yes"
while edit !='exit':
    keyfield=input("enter the game name of the record you want to edit. ")
    keyfield="'"+keyfield+"'"
    field=input("enter the field you want to change. ")

    newVal=input("enter the new data for this field. ")
    #try:
    cursor.execute("UPDATE tblGames SET " + field + "=" + newVal +  " WHERE game = " + keyfield)
    conn.commit()
    print("\nRecord Updated\n")
    #except:
        #print("invalid game name or field entered.")
    edit=input("type 'exit' to stop editing, or press enter to continue. \n")
    showtable()
```

The except statement is commented out so I could see the error message for the try statement. Again, it works perfectly when I attempt to update an enrty to a number, but when I attempt to update to a string, it gives the error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/Users/12smi/Documents/school/computing/SQL/database with add and remove function.py", line 99, in 
>       amendRec()
>     File "C:/Users/12smi/Documents/school/computing/SQL/database with add and remove function.py", line 82, in amendRec
>       cursor.execute("UPDATE tblGames SET " + field + "=" + newVal +  " WHERE game = " + keyfield)
>   sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: Adventure

('Adventure' is the string I input that time)

I have no idea why this happens, so any help would be great :)

Comment: I really can't keep up the fight against string formatting for queries. Please just don't use it, it's a big SQL injection risk and it leads to code being slower and less legible. As for your error, we can't see the table so presumably `Adventure` doesn't exist in the schema

Comment: `"UPDATE tblGames SET {} = ? WHERE game = ?".format(field), (newfield, newVal))`. But this is really error-prone because of user input and still unsafe.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting that error because you tried to execute

```
UPDATE tblGames SET genre=Adventure WHERE game = 'Shadow of the Colossus';
```

while you propably meant to execute

```
UPDATE tblGames SET genre='Adventure' WHERE game = 'Shadow of the Colossus';
```

If you just go and make that change it'll work, but I will be cross with you, because your code is **dangerous**.

There's a bigger problem in your code that the comments have already pointed out. You're splicing together your query using unsanitized strings, which is an antipattern. Python's sqlite3 library allows you to bind parameters to your queries. Any `?` in your query will be replaced by a value of your choosing (example below).

You have another problem, though. You cannot bind a column name as a parameter. Trying to do so would have `'columnName'` in the query instead of `columnName`. There's no safe way to do it, because it's another antipattern. But since we're here, let's at least do it in a safe way. We will have to embed the column name into the query, but we can't embed just any user input for fear of SQL injection. Therefore, we have to make sure that the string we embed is a column name and only a column name. In other words, we will have to **sanitize** the input.

The code below will sanitize the column name so that only valid column names will make it into the query. It also embeds the other parameters using sqlite3's functionality, which sanitizes the inputs for you.

```
def amendRec():
    edit = "yes"
    while edit != 'exit':
        keyfield = input("enter the game name of the record you want to edit. ")
        field = input("enter the field you want to change. ")

        # Check whether the specified colmun exists or not.
        # Any SQL injection will fail this test.
        query = "PRAGMA table_info ('tblGames');"
        columnExists = False
        for columnName in map(lambda x: x[1], cur.execute(query)):
            if columnName == field:
                columnExists = True

        if columnExists:
            # field can only be one of the column names since it's sanitized above.
            query = "UPDATE tblGames SET {} = ? WHERE game = ? ;".format(field)
            new_val = input("enter the new data for this field. ")
            # We pass in a tuple containing our desired parameters as the second parameter of cursor.execute.
            # new_val will replace the first ? and keyfield will replace the second ?.
            cursor.execute(query, (new_val, keyfield))
            conn.commit()
            print("\nRecord Updated\n")
        else:
            print("Sorry, that column doesn't exist.")

        edit = input("type 'exit' to stop editing, or press enter to continue. \n")
        showtable()
```

Ideally, you'd have `field` be a multiple-choice input rather than a text input. That way you can be more certain that it's safe and you'd have to make one less query to the database.